# Redirecting output of launchfile called from Python

Tags: python, output, ros

I have a simple piece of code which runs a specified launchfile:

```
roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
file = [(roslaunch.rlutil.resolve_launch_arguments(cli)[0], cli[2:])]
launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid, file)
```

Execution of the launchfile stuff generates lots of logging output on stdout/err, so the actual script's output is getting lost.

Is it possible to somehow redirect or disable printing it on the screen?

Comment: why not redirect the stdout and stderror for this script to a file or /dev/null?

Comment: What output are you wanting to redirect exactly? Ros log statements or python print statements?

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. via env vars (export).
2. via python logging module.

**Using env vars**

- You can set ROS logging to a /dev/null like file system.
- See ROS env vars: https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

*export ROS_LOG_DIR=/black/hole*

Use https://github.com/abbbi/nullfsvfs to create the dir.

**Using python logging**

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("rospy").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels

Answer (score 1):

How about redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to files? As long as you redirect them before your calls to `roslaunch` it should put all the output into the files you point to (or `/dev/null` to ignore it).

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('redirect.out','w') 
sys.stderr = open('redirect.err','w')
```